# symfony easyadmin form field type entity with filter list

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use symfony 3.4 and easycorp/easyadmin-bundle 1.17

This is my class "Quotation", the "artisan" field is an "under registration" of the "Person" entity (person.type = 1) :

```
class Quotation
{
/** others fields... */

/**
 *  1 => 'artisan', 2 => 'customer'
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="artisanQuotations", cascade= { "persist" })
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artisan_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $artisan;

    /** getters and setters ... */
```

I have a problem with a form field using a custom field type

```
form:
    fields:
        ...
        - { property: 'artisan', label: '', type: 'AppBundle\Form\Field\ArtisanType' }
```

I created this form field type to be able to filter the list thanks to the query_builder :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('artisan', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Person',
        'label' => false,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('person')
                ->where('person.type = 1');
        },
        'attr' => array('data-widget' => 'select2'),
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded'=> false
    ));
}
```

my form is displayed perfectly well but when i submit this form i have an error :

> Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Person", "array" given

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: my problem is not solved, I updated the post, can someone help me because I can not find any solution to this problem

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the buildForm method you should use configureOptions here. That way your form is not extended by another subform which results in the array.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArtisanType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
    * @param \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Person',
            'label' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('person')
                    ->where('person.type = 1');
            },
            'attr' => array('data-widget' => 'select2'),
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded'=> false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
    * @return string|null
    */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```