# symfony easyadmin query_builder static method inject token_storage

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use symfony 3.4 and easycorp/easyadmin-bundle 1.17

I am trying to use a static function for the query_builder options:

```
form:
    fields:
        ...
        - { property: 'customer', label: '', type_options: { query_builder: ['AppBundle\Repository\PersonRepository', 'getCustomer'] } }
```

the repository :

```
class PersonRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public static function getCustomer(EntityRepository $er)
    {
        //        dump($tokeStorage);
        dump($er);
        die;
        $user = null; // how to get token_storage ?
        $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('person')
            ->leftJoin('person.userCreated', 'user')
            ->andWhere('person.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', 2)
        ;
        if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $user->getRoles())) {
            $query->andWhere('user.company = :company');
            $query->setParameter('company', $user->getCompany());
        } else {
            $query->andWhere('user.id = :user');
            $query->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

I need to inject the token storage, how can I do?

I opened 3 posts revolving around this topic or I think that the solution "static" will not be the good one but none of the 3 solutions gives me the expected result

[[symfony easyadmin custom form builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313338/symfony-easyadmin-custom-form-builder][1])

[[symfony easyadmin form field type entity with filter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199397/symfony-easyadmin-form-field-type-entity-with-filter-list][2])

thanks in advance

Comment: Dependency injection and static's don't really play together very nicely.  Plus your PersonRepository already extends EntityRepository so injecting another repository does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: is there another way to pass the current user to the query_builder of this field?

Comment: Use a setter to inject the token storage and configure your services.yaml file accordingly.  Though in this case I'd probably just pass $roles as an argument to getCustomer.  And if you had to ask multiple times then maybe you should take a step back and really look at what you are asking.